Flutter Android Fastlane Permission denied pulling captured screenshots from the emulator
Most of the steps of Fastlane Android Screengrab work as intended: building my app in debug with the given environment parameter, building the Android tests, running the Android tests in the emulator, and storing the screenshots on the device (see logcat output below) however when Fastlane attempts to pull the screenshots from the emulator it stops polling locations after a "permission denied" error.
[20:55:07]: Pulling captured screenshots from the device
ls: /sdcard/io.outright.my_flutter_app/screengrab: No such file or directory
[20:55:07]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/io.outright.my_flutter_app/app_screengrab: Permission denied
[20:55:07]: Exit status: 1
[20:55:07]: Make sure you've used Screengrab.screenshot() in your tests and that your expected tests are being run.

I have confirmed that I am using Screengrab.screenshot() in my tests and my expected tests are being run. This is from logcat of the emulator while the test ran:
... Screengrab    io.outright.my_flutter_app      D  Using screenshot storage directory: /data/user/0/io.outright.my_flutter_app/app_screengrab/en_US/images/screenshots
... Screengrab    io.outright.my_flutter_app      D  Captured screenshot "0_StartScreen.png"
... Screengrab    io.outright.my_flutter_app      D  Using screenshot storage directory: /data/user/0/io.outright.my_flutter_app/app_screengrab/en_US/images/screenshots
... Screengrab    io.outright.my_flutter_app      D  Captured screenshot "1_SetupScreen.png"
... Screengrab    io.outright.my_flutter_app      D  Using screenshot storage directory: /data/user/0/io.outright.my_flutter_app/app_screengrab/en_US/images/screenshots
... Screengrab    io.outright.my_flutter_app      D  Captured screenshot "2_GameScreen.png"
... Screengrab    io.outright.my_flutter_app      D  Using screenshot storage directory: /data/user/0/io.outright.my_flutter_app/app_screengrab/en_US/images/screenshots

Attempt to see these files with adb shows the same permission error:
$ adb shell ls /data/user/0/io.outright.my_flutter_app/app_screengrab/en_US/images/screenshots

ls: /data/user/0/io.outright.my_flutter_app/app_screengrab/en_US/images/screenshots: Permission denied

There used to be a use_adb_root parameter for Fastlane but it is now deprecated and does not work in any version since 2.0
Environment

macOS Sonoma 14.7.1
Chip Apple M1 Pro
Fastlane 2.225.0
Fastlane installed and run with ruby 3.2.2 and Bundler 2.5.22
Android Emulator running Pixel 6a API 34 with UpsideDownCake Android 14.0 arm64-v8a

Screengrabfile
app_package_name('io.outright.my_flutter_app')
use_tests_in_packages(['io.outright.my_flutter_app'])
tests_package_name('io.outright.my_flutter_app.test')

app_apk_path('../build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk')
tests_apk_path('../build/app/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk')

test_instrumentation_runner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

locales(['en-US'])

clear_previous_screenshots(true)

Fastfile
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do

  desc "Capture screenshots"
  lane :screenshots do
    sh("flutter", "build", "apk", "--debug")
    build_android_app(
      task: 'assemble',
      build_type: 'AndroidTest'
    )
    capture_android_screenshots
  end

end

app/build.gradle
...

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'tools.fastlane:screengrab:2.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0"
}

Logs
$ bundle exec fastlane screenshots                                                                                                                                                 

[✔]                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                               
|                                            Used plugins                                             |                                                                                                               
+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                               
| Plugin                             | Version | Action                                               |                                                                                                               
+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                               
| fastlane-plugin-versioning_android | 0.1.1   | android_get_version_code, android_get_version_name,  |                                                                                                               
|                                    |         | android_set_version_code, android_set_version_name   |                                                                                                               
+------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[20:54:38]: ------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                            
[20:54:38]: --- Step: default_platform ---                                                                                                                                                                            
[20:54:38]: ------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                            
[20:54:38]: Driving the lane 'android screenshots'                                                                                                                                                                  
[20:54:38]: -----------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         
[20:54:38]: --- Step: flutter build apk --debug --dart-define\=DEMO\=true ---                                                                                                                                         
[20:54:38]: -----------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                         
[20:54:38]: $ flutter build apk --debug --dart-define\=DEMO\=true                                                                                                                                                     
[20:54:38]: ▸ Changing current working directory to: /Users/kaye375751/om/MyFlutterApp                                                                                                                           
[20:54:45]: ▸ Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              5.0s                                                                                                                                
[20:54:46]: ▸ ✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk                                                                                                                                                     
[20:54:46]: ---------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                         
[20:54:46]: --- Step: assembleAndroidTest ---                                                                                                                                                                         
[20:54:46]: ---------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                         
[20:54:46]: $ /Users/kaye375751/om/MyFlutterApp/android/gradlew assembleAndroidTest -p .   
[20:54:47]: ▸ > Task :gradle:compileJava NO-SOURCE                                                                                                                                                                    
[20:54:47]: ▸ > Task :gradle:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
[20:54:47]: ▸ > Task :gradle:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
[20:54:47]: ▸ > Task :gradle:processResources UP-TO-DATE
[20:54:47]: ▸ > Task :gradle:classes UP-TO-DATE
[20:54:47]: ▸ > Task :gradle:jar UP-TO-DATE

.........many Gradle tasks.........

[20:54:50]: ▸ BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s                                                                       
[20:54:50]: ▸ 280 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 279 up-to-date
[20:54:50]: Couldn't find any new signed apk files...                           
[20:54:50]: -----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                 
[20:54:50]: --- Step: capture_android_screenshots ---                                                                                                                                                                 
[20:54:50]: -----------------------------------------
[20:54:50]: Successfully loaded '/Users/kaye375751/om/MyFlutterApp/android/fastlane/Screengrabfile' 
                                                     
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          Detected Values from './fastlane/Screengrabfile'                          |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| app_package_name            | io.outright.my_flutter_app                                      |                                                                                                                
| use_tests_in_packages       | ["io.outright.my_flutter_app"]                                  |
| tests_package_name          | io.outright.my_flutter_app.test                                 |
| app_apk_path                | ../build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk                         |
| tests_apk_path              | ../build/app/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk |
| test_instrumentation_runner | androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner                              |
| locales                     | ["en-US"]                                                            |
| clear_previous_screenshots  | true                                                                 |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
                                                                                                           
[20:54:50]: The `aapt` command could not be found relative to your provided ANDROID_HOME at /Users/kaye375751/Library/Android/sdk
[20:54:50]: Please ensure that the Android SDK is installed and you have the build tools downloaded                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                           
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    Summary for screengrab 1.0.0                                    |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| android_home                | /Users/kaye375751/Library/Android/sdk                                |
| locales                     | ["en-US"]                                                            |
| clear_previous_screenshots  | true                                                                 |
| output_directory            | fastlane/metadata/android                                            |
| skip_open_summary           | false                                                                |
| app_package_name            | io.outright.my_flutter_app                                      |
| tests_package_name          | io.outright.my_flutter_app.test                                 |
| use_tests_in_packages       | ["io.outright.my_flutter_app"]                                  |
| test_instrumentation_runner | androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner                              |
| ending_locale               | en-US                                                                |
| app_apk_path                | ../build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk                         |
| tests_apk_path              | ../build/app/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk |
| device_type                 | phone                                                                |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
                                                     
[20:54:50]: Clearing phoneScreenshots within fastlane/metadata/android
[20:54:50]: $ adb devices -l                 
[20:54:51]: ▸ List of devices attached
[20:54:51]: ▸ emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone64_arm64 model:sdk_gphone64_arm64 device:emu64a transport_id:2
[20:54:51]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell echo \$EXTERNAL_STORAGE            
[20:54:51]: ▸ /sdcard                                                                                      
[20:54:51]: Cleaning screenshots on device                                                                 
ls: /sdcard/io.outright.my_flutter_app/screengrab: No such file or directory
[20:54:51]: Exit status: 1                                                                                 
ls: /data/data/io.outright.my_flutter_app/app_screengrab: No such file or directory
[20:54:51]: Exit status: 1                                                                                 
[20:54:51]: The `aapt` command could not be found on your system, so your app APK could not be validated
[20:54:51]: Installing app APK                                                                             
[20:54:51]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 install -r ../build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
[20:54:51]: ▸ Performing Streamed Install
[20:54:52]: ▸ Success
[20:54:52]: Installing tests APK
[20:54:52]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 install -r ../build/app/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
[20:54:52]: ▸ Performing Streamed Install
[20:54:52]: ▸ Success
[20:54:52]: Granting the permission necessary to change locales on the device
[20:54:52]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant io.outright.my_flutter_app android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
[20:54:52]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
[20:54:52]: ▸ 34
[20:54:52]: Granting the permissions necessary to access device external storage
[20:54:52]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant io.outright.my_flutter_app android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
[20:54:52]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm grant io.outright.my_flutter_app android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
[20:54:52]: Running tests for locale: en-US
[20:54:52]: $ adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument --no-window-animation -w \
-e testLocale en_US \
-e endingLocale en_US \
-e package io.outright.my_flutter_app \
io.outright.my_flutter_app.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
[20:55:00]: ▸ io.outright.my_flutter_app.ScreengrabTest:s_glBindAttribLocation: bind attrib 0 name position
[20:55:00]: ▸ s_glBindAttribLocation: bind attrib 1 name color
[20:55:00]: ▸ s_glBindAttribLocation: bind attrib 2 name localCoord
[20:55:07]: ▸ .
[20:55:07]: ▸ Time: 13.232
[20:55:07]: ▸ OK (1 test)
[20:55:07]: Pulling captured screenshots from the device
ls: /sdcard/io.outright.my_flutter_app/screengrab: No such file or directory
[20:55:07]: Exit status: 1
ls: /data/data/io.outright.my_flutter_app/app_screengrab: Permission denied
[20:55:07]: Exit status: 1
[20:55:07]: Make sure you've used Screengrab.screenshot() in your tests and that your expected tests are being run.
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                       Lane Context                        |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM                    | android             |
| PLATFORM_NAME                       | android             |
| LANE_NAME                           | android screenshots |
| GRADLE_BUILD_TYPE                   | AndroidTest         |
| GRADLE_ALL_APK_OUTPUT_PATHS         | []                  |
| GRADLE_ALL_AAB_OUTPUT_PATHS         | []                  |
| GRADLE_ALL_OUTPUT_JSON_OUTPUT_PATHS | []                  |
| GRADLE_ALL_MAPPING_TXT_OUTPUT_PATHS | []                  |
+-------------------------------------+---------------------+
[20:55:07]: Called from Fastfile at line 62
[20:55:07]: ```
[20:55:07]:     60:           build_type: 'AndroidTest'
[20:55:07]:     61:         )
[20:55:07]:  => 62:         capture_android_screenshots
[20:55:07]:     63:         upload_to_play_store
[20:55:07]:     64:       end
[20:55:07]: ```
[20:55:07]: No screenshots were detected ❌

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                             fastlane summary                             |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                                              | Time (in s) |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform                                    | 0           |
| 2    | flutter build apk --debug --dart-define\=DEMO\=true | 7           |
| 3    | assembleAndroidTest                                 | 4           |
|    | capture_android_screenshots                         | 16          |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+

[20:55:07]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] No screenshots were detected ❌


Create new issue https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/28797

I suspect the problem is related to this message in the logs: "The aapt command could not be found relative to your provided ANDROID_HOME?"
